# How to clone partitions from larger disk to smaller disk

Tags: partition, clonezilla

I have a disk with 1000gb and ~7partitions that take about 210 GB, and I'm trying to clone those partitions to 240 GB disk.
I've tried doing it with clonezilla boot up USB. Using `dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1` it says that it creates the partition on target sdb disk, so I turn it off and boot up again, and the partitions aren't there. Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: You have to make the partitions smaller so they fit on the smaller disc , then clone using any tool you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dd` command that you are using isn't copying any partitions in particular but the entirety of `/dev/sdc` which isn't going to work because `/dev/sdc` is ~4 times the size of `/dev/sdb`.

What you need to do is create partitions of equal size on `/dev/sdb` and then use either `dd` or `cat` to clone the partions separately.

Make sure that there are no mounted filesystems on `/dev/sdb`. After creating the partitions on `/dev/sdb`:

`dd if=/dev/sdc3 of=/dev/sdb3 bs=2M`

`dd if=/dev/sdc4 of=/dev/sdb4 bs=2M`

For better (and quicker) performance, use `cat`:

`cat /dev/sdc3 > /dev/sdb3`

`cat /dev/sdc4 > /dev/sdb4`

And so on and so forth.

Comment: @roaima `cat` does indeed give better performance unless other options are used with `dd` (which I forgot to include). I've just always used `dd`. I'll add `cat` to my answer.

Comment: `cat` gives me "permission denied" even as `root`, but `dd` works great. Also with `dd` you can add the parameter `status=progress` to get a running progress of the copy.

Comment: @lurker If there is a concern when using `cat`, ask a question regarding it and include everything that is being done including the disk information, the command(s), any error messages, and the actual and expected results.

Comment: yes I can do that. I just thought it might improve this answer if a couple of additional points were made, such as possible advantage of using `dd`, or possible restrictions when using `cat`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you cannot clone from a bigger drive to a smaller drive.

But there are workarounds.

- You can shrink (and maybe move) the partitions on the bigger drive, so that they all reside within the limits of the smaller drive (with a small amount of drive space reserved for a backup partition table at the tail end in case of a GUID partition table, GPT).

  Beware, that if you move the head end of a boot partition (the root partition may be a boot partition), the bootloader must be reinstalled in order to find it. This is possible, but a complication.
- Then you can clone this part of the bigger drive, and if a GUID partition table, GPT, afterwards fix the backup partition table for example with `gdisk`.

  I would still recommend to clone the 'whole' drive, from `/dev/sdx` to `/dev/sdy`, where `x` is the device letter of the source drive and `y` is the device letter of the target drive. Cloning with `dd` or similar tools will be truncated, when the target drive is full.
- There are also other things, that can create problems. A few minutes ago I wrote a list of things to watch out for, when you intend to clone a drive. See the following link, [Cloning from one drive to another drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097683/lubuntu-18-10-x64-installed-on-usb-stick-clone-to-usb-stick-2/1097733#1097733).