# Clonezilla - cloning usb flash drive to smaller usb flash drive

Tags: clonezilla

The usb drive i want to clone is slightly bigger than the target usb drive - with about 1gb bigger, but the data on the source usb drive is with smaller size than the size of the target usb drive.

I booted Clonezilla from live usb, selected source and target usb drives, in advanced options i check -icds and in partion table option window i select -k1. Then i started Clonezilla operation and it took about 20 minutes to finish the operation but in the end i get this error: `target seek error invalid argument`

And at the bottom of the screen it showed this: `Partclone fail, please check /var/log/partclone.log.`

Is there a way to clone my usb to smaller usb or it can't be done?

Answer (score 1):

I would use gparted to shrink the partition size down so that it is smaller than the target. Then I would perform the clone operation on the drive. Or use dd if=/path/to/drivewithpartitionnumber of=/path/to/destination/drive

Comment: Do you mean i can clone the usb with `dd` command? The usb drive i am trying to clone is bootable. Will the target usb drive become bootable if i use the `dd` command? Also, do i have to format and partition the target usb before using the `dd` command?

Comment: If you use the dd command to make it so it boots. You will have to use the base drive, like: dd if=/dev/sda of=/path/to/new/usb, ignore the error about size. Use gparted or similar to fix size error on the new usb after you remount the new usb. Should work just fine.

Comment: Trying to put larger into smaller is always problimatic, that is why I suggested shrinking the partition down so it could be copied. This would however not be bootable because the MBR would not be copied in that way. The way I suggested in the comments should work as I have done this succesfuly for friends.

Comment: Why shrinking the partition should matter? I am using disk to disk option in Clonezilla, not partition to partition. Or you mean i have to use the option 'partition to partition' after shrinking the partition with gparted?

Comment: @user1800997, See also [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/485373/how-to-clone-partitions-from-larger-disk-to-smaller-disk/485393#485393). If you clone without shrinking some partition(s), at least a part of a partition will be truncated, when the cloning reaches the end of the target drive.

Comment: The only option that would work is, partition to partition. However, that will not yield a bootable drive. I only became aware you wanted it bootable in the comments. That is why I suggested what I did. The easiest solution is to get a bigger destination drive. That is pretty much what I am saying. what is said in that link is correct. You would then have to reinstall the boot loader.

Comment: @MichaelProkopec, I have cloned successfully drive to drive when all partitions fit within the target drive (that the end of all partitions will be reached before the end of the target drive is reached). But if GPT, the backup partition table must be fixed.

Comment: @sudodus Correct... fscking works too.

Comment: I used gparted to shrink the partition but now the usb won't boot. I guess the boot sector or the partition table was damaged during the partition resizing.

Comment: After the resize did you check it for errors? Manage flags to make sure the boot flag was still set.